# Synonyms for DNS Tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I've just been around filling in some tag wikis for a bunch of DNS related tags, and I noticed the following:

[a-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/a-record)
[cname](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cname)
[ptr](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ptr)

[a-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/a-record) doesn't fit the same naming scheme as the rest. Probably because [a](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/a) is not a valid tag (doesn't make sense on its own).

Should we merge [cname](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cname) to [cname-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cname-record) and [ptr](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ptr) to [ptr-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ptr-record) (and for [txt](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/txt) to [txt-record](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/txt-record), which I've actually already done because [txt](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/txt) on its own is meaningless)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think the consistency is worth it.

Comment: That's good enough for me ;)